# Reading through a text file to find a specific string and read another string related to it

Tags: python, string, for-loop, foreach

Before I get started I want to note that this is Homework and I do not want an answer on a silver platter(not that I expected that). I want help with my logic.

I am trying to make a program that reads through the text file located [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~csci141/Homeworks/HwkC/athletes.txt).

One function takes a parameter year and and looks through the file for that year and counts the medals won by athletes in that year and returns the total medals.

A second function takes the year, athletes last name, and first name as parameters and reports that athletes medals won. I understand how to open the file, and how to use  a for loop and readline command.

I do not know how I would go about getting the number of medals from the athlete if I am not directly looking for the number itself. If someone could assist me with reworking my logic that would be appreciated. I will post my code so far for reference.

```
def countByYear(year):
line = 0
medals = 0
with open("athletes.txt", encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = f.readline()
        if s == year:
            break
            line2 = f.readline()
            for line2 in f:
                if line2.isdigit():
                    int(line2)
                    medals+=line2
                    break
    print(medals)
```

Comment: can the code after the first `break` ever execute?

Comment: why not `if line  == year`?

Comment: I thought line was a necessary counter that I would have to increment to go to the next line?

Comment: @darksoulsfan no, `for line in file_obj` will iterate through each line in turn, no need to `readline` each time.

Comment: you are already iterating over the file object `f`

Comment: Personally I'd parse this using regex, build a dict out of it, then search the dict rather than trying to search the file each time.

Comment: Ok so `for line in f` is already stating `line = f.readline()` ? Am I understanding this part correctly or no?

Comment: @darksoulsfan yes exactly! :)

Comment: Decompose the problem. The first order of business is parsing the file. Notice that there are 4 lines of lastname, firstname, year, medals, followed by an empty line. So you want a function that can read 4 lines into variables, skip the empty and return the data. Have you gotten as far as the `yield` operator yet? It would be a great iterator.

Comment: My teacher recommended utilizing the strip() function. I need to first read the python documents to see what this does again. @tdelaney I have not gotten their yet.

Comment: I think I just realized something. The medals is the line right after the year. After reading the line with the year. I just need to go only to the next line, convert it into an int, add it to a counter, and keep going. At least I think so. (talking about the first function)

Comment: Just wanted to update that I did solve this problem. Not the fancy way but it produces desired results. To avoid other students looking to copy code, I am not going to post my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get fancy, try this:

```
def parse_file(f):
    competitors = []
    for line in f:
        last, first, year, medals, _ = line.strip(), next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(), next(f)
        competitors.append({"last":last, "first":first,
                            "year":year, "medals":medals})
    return competitors

def count_by_year(year, competitors_dict):
    # year must be a string
    year = str(year)
    return sum(competitor['medals'] for competitor in competitors_dict if competitor['year'] == year)

def years_by_athlete(firstname, lastname, year, competitors_dict):
    for competitor in competitors_dict:
        if competitor['first'] == firstname and \
           competitor['last'] == lastname and \
           competitor['year'] == year:
            return competitor['medals']
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('path/to/your/file', 'r') as f:
        competitors = parse_file(f)
    num_medals_by_year = count_by_year(1900, competitors)
    num_medals_by_athlete = years_by_athlete("DARIA", "PRATT", "1900", competitors)
```

Remember that file objects are iterators in Python, so if you're reading a file described below:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
This is the fourth line
This is a blank line
```

Then you can do

```
for line in file:
    firstline = line
    secondline = next(file)
    thirdline = next(file)
    fourthline = next(file)
    _ = next(file)
```

The `next` built-in advances the iterator. The code runs through the whole file in 5-line chunks, assigning the last line to `_` (which is a common Python idiom for "We don't use this one", e.g. `for _ in range(10)` to do something 10 times). Then we construct a list of dictionaries out of it so we can reference it later. This is much faster than reading the file every time we look something up. We use `strip` on each one (other than the line we're throwing away because...why bother?) to remove trailing whitespace. This includes the newline character at the end of each line (e.g. to match a file that reads `This is the first line` exactly, you'd have to look for `"This is the first line\n"`)

Then using the built-in `sum` function, we use a generator expression to give every `'medals'` value if the `'year'` value matches what we're given. This unrolls to:

```
s = 0
for competitor in competitors_dict:
    if competitors_dict['year'] == year:
        s += competitors_dict['medals']
return s
```

As far as your second function, all you need is a series of `if` conditions. Iterate through `competitors_dict` and make sure that the `'first'`, `'last'`, and `'year'` fields all match your arguments, then return the `'medals'` field. Just that simple :)

Comment: Yeah.. I realize my error in my statement. It takes those parameters and yields medals won by that athlete specifically.

Comment: @darksoulsfan I see. I've edited my code with a lengthy description and a function definition for your second problem